# Looking for an Xamarin.Forms bluetooth library for IOS that will pick up already paired devices to my iphone

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

I've got an existing PCL Xamarin forms app which works great. New requirement is to connect a Biocontrol Hhr3000 scanner via Bluetooth to the .ios version of my project. Workflow is, i first connect and pair the scanner to my iPhone over Bluetooth. I need a non LE (low energy) Bluetooth library which i can use to work with this. All i can find on the internet is all examples of LE Bluetooth so as it stands i cant get the iPhone to pick up the scanner via normal Bluetooth pairing.

Please point me in the right direction.  I'm looking for an ios implementation thats simple like this one for android: https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/connect-a-barcode-reader-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-via-bluetooth/

Answer (score 0):

If the device is [Mfi Certified](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) by Apple, then you can use the [External Accessory Framework](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/ExternalAccessory/) to interact with the bluetooth device. If you can pair it, I have to assume it is Mfi Certified.

Comment: Thanks for the info